# how to add another view using layout inflatter

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I created mainLayout with two  buttons

add: to add other layout

remove : to remove other layout.

```
    <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
             android:textStyle="bold"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:text="Add View"
             android:onClick="addView" />

      <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
             android:textStyle="bold"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:text="Remove View"
             android:onClick="removeView" />
```

now i wrote following code to add the view
when I click on addView button

```
               LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout,null);


    mainLayout.addView(view);
```

**the view is added below the main layout**.
But I want the view to add in middle of the screen not at the bottom of screen.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line and put ur parent view.

```
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout,PARENT_VIEW_OBJECT);
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

get the parentLayout like this

```
parentLayout=(YourParentLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
```

then

```
parentLayout.addView(yourview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code, its working fine for me

```
private View view = null ;
Button addbutton = null;
ViewGroup parent = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = null;

inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
addbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainxml);


addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null);
            parent.addView(view);
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put an empty LinearLayout placeholder at the top of your main layout where you want your view to be and add the view to that instead of the main layout.

You can adjust the placeholder first and modify it's location and looks.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/placeholder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
..../>

<Button
..../>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html) it holds a place until .inflate() is called.  That way the layout isn't taking resources until it's needed.